# Einstein NBA : is there a way to pass recommendationId to Flow Action?

Tags: einstein-recommendations, einstein-next-best-action

In a specific use case, I need to pass the recommendation Id to the Flow Action in order to update Opportunity record with the recommendation ID, can anyone help me please ?

If it's not possible, is there any alternative to do this ? The business need is to relate the Recommendation to the Opportunity and there's an API that takes information from Opportunity, in this way after the recommendation has been chosen we can take information from it too.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

- Name: inputRecommendation
- Type: Record Variable
- Object: Recommendation
- Availability Outside the Flow: check off the "input" box

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).